# How can I simplify these formulas?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I got these formulas from  computation:

```
{-((a k (3 + b - 3 r))/(-θ^2 (3 + b - 2 r) (-1 + r) + 
   k (-3 + b (2 + b) + 2 r - 2 b r + r^2))),
 (a k (3 + b - r) (-1 + r))/(-θ^2 (3 + b - 2 r) (-1 + r) + 
  k (-3 + b (2 + b) + 2 r - 2 b r + r^2))}
```

The question is these formulas is not as simple as in the article:

```
{(a k (3 r - b - 3 ))/(
 r^2 k + (2 r - b - 3) ((k (1 - b) - θ^2 (1 - r)))), (
 a k (1 - r) (r - b - 3 ))/(
 r^2 k + (2 r - b - 3) ((k (1 - b) - θ^2 (1 - r))))}
```

I tried `FullSimplify` but it did not work, What can I do to get the same result from the article ? Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you look at the output of `LeafCount`  you'll find the first formula has 46 and the second is 48 in the first set. While the ones you are trying to simplify to, i.e. the second set,  the first has `LeafCount` of 46 and 49. So according to Mathematica's Simplify, there is nothing to simplify. You can override using  `LeafCount` as the measure to use for simplification if you want.

Answer (score 6):

As you described it, your question has no sense. Indeed, first of all, one can check if these two expressions are equal:

```
exprA = {-((a k (3 + b - 3 r))/(-\[Theta]^2 (3 + b - 2 r) (-1 + r) + 
        k (-3 + b (2 + b) + 2 r - 2 b r + r^2))), (a k (3 + b - 
        r) (-1 + r))/(-\[Theta]^2 (3 + b - 2 r) (-1 + r) + 
      k (-3 + b (2 + b) + 2 r - 2 b r + r^2))};


exprB = {(a k (3 r - b - 
        3))/(r^2 k + (2 r - b - 
         3) ((k (1 - b) - \[Theta]^2 (1 - r)))), (a k (1 - r) (r - 
        b - 3))/(r^2 k + (2 r - b - 
         3) ((k (1 - b) - \[Theta]^2 (1 - r))))};


Simplify[exprA - exprB]

(*  {0, 0}  *)
```

So, we made sure that `exprA` and `exprB` are equal to one another.

Further, the main misunderstanding comes from the fact that you did not explain why do you need this expression in precisely that form.
It is trivial that one can write an expression in several different forms. Some of them can be more advantageous than others, but then one needs to understand, why?

As @Nasser explained in his comment, Mma has its own internal "understanding" of what is the most advantageous form. This understanding can be changed. Have a look at the `ComplexityFunction`, its use is, however, not easy.

There is another way to do it, and I show its example below. However, it requires some programming, and I do not understand if it pays off.

OK, for the sake of example let us look at the first component of the vectors: `exprA[[1]]` and `exprB[[1]]`. We see that they differ from one another by (1) the sign minus in front of the former, and (2) in the latter the term `kr^2` is separated out.

Let us start with the latter transformation.

Step 1: we expand the denominator:

```
expr1 = ExpandDenominator[exprA[[1]]]

(*  -((a k (3 + b - 3 r))/(-3 k + 2 b k + b^2 k + 2 k r - 2 b k r + 
  k r^2 + 3 \[Theta]^2 + b \[Theta]^2 - 5 r \[Theta]^2 - 
  b r \[Theta]^2 + 2 r^2 \[Theta]^2))  *)
```

Step 2: Let us apply Hold to the term `kr^2` to be able later to transform everything excluding this term:

```
expr2 = MapAt[Hold, expr1, {5, 1, 6}]

(*  -((a k (3 + b - 3 r))/(-3 k + 2 b k + b^2 k + 2 k r - 2 b k r + 
  3 \[Theta]^2 + b \[Theta]^2 - 5 r \[Theta]^2 - b r \[Theta]^2 + 
  2 r^2 \[Theta]^2 + Hold[k r^2]))  *)
```

Step 3: Now we can simplify the expression in the denominator. After the simplification we can remove the Hold function:

```
expr3 = MapAt[Simplify, expr2, {5, 1}] // ReleaseHold

(*  -((a k (3 + b - 3 r))/(
 k r^2 + (3 + b - 2 r) ((-1 + b) k - (-1 + r) \[Theta]^2))) *)
```

Step 4: as you can see we got almost the necessary expression. All that is left to us is to change the sign in the numerator:

```
MapAt[Times[Hold[Evaluate[Times[#, -1]]], -1] &, 
  expr3, {4}] // ReleaseHold

(*  (a k (-3 - b + 3 r))/(
k r^2 + (3 + b - 2 r) ((-1 + b) k - (-1 + r) \[Theta]^2))  *)
```

To better see the result, I put it below as an image:

[image]

Done.

The analogous approach can be applied to the second component of the vector. Try it.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks! this problem came from my friend. I tried a lot but still can not solve this problem, so I posted it on this platform.

Comment: @任天一 It is right that you asked this question. My point is that if there are several versions of the same expression, Mma returns only one of them. In general, we always can get any other of the possible equivalent versions. However, it is always better to understand, why do we want this version, but not any other. There can be so many reasons, that I do not want to list them. If there is such a reason, it is OK one should do it. In this question, I had a feeling that your friend simply wanted to check the equivalence of the two results, which is another problem.

Comment: Thanks! I get it!